# Clang + pycparser fail to parse pythread.h header from CPython 3.7

Tags: python, c, gcc, clang, pycparser

`Clang` + `pycparser` fail to parse `pythread.h` header from CPython 3.7, but this was working in CPython 3.7-dev in Travis CI.

```
opt/python/3.7.0/include/python3.7m/pythread.h:122:5: error: "Require native
      threads. See https://bugs.python.org/issue31370"
#   error "Require native threads. See https://bugs.python.org/issue31370"
```

It is not obvious whether I should try `gcc` instead of `clang`, pass specific threading flags to compiler or extend pycparser with additional "faked" libc headers due to code not compliant with C99?

More details in this issue:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/609#issuecomment-412959577

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed, like Eli B. suggested it was a missing `#define` to the compiler:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/py37/tools/geninterop/geninterop.py#L177

`"-D _POSIX_THREADS"`